# Java/Groovy: Create and read a list of two objects

Tags: java, groovy

How do I define and iterate over a list of two objects (Foo, Bar)?

What I tried:

```
// create
def fooBar = new ArrayList<Foo, Bar>()
fooBar.add(new Foo())
fooBar.add(new Bar())
fooBar.add(new Foo()) // << shouldn't be allowed or overwrite first foo

def fooBars = new ArrayList<List<Foo, Bar>>()
fooBars << fooBar

// read
fooBars.each { fooBar ->
  def foo = fooBar[0]
  def bar = fooBar[1]
  // do something with foo and bar
}
```

What I want:

```
// pseudo code
def fooBar = new ???<Foo, Bar>()
fooBar.set(new Foo())
fooBar.set(new Bar())

def fooBars = new ArrayList<???>()
fooBars << fooBar

fooBars.each { fooBar ->
  def foo = fooBar[???] // 0, 'foo', ..?
  def bar = fooBar[???]
  // do something with foo and bar
}
```

If creating my own FooBar class is the solution I'm fine, I just hope there is a more simple solution.

Comment: You could try `new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Foo, Bar>(...)`

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you're trying to do. Are you trying to create a list where each element of the list is either a Foo or a Bar? If so, then you want `ArrayList<Object>`. It sounds like you may also be trying to create a list of pairs of Foos and Bars, in which case you would either need to use some `Pair<T1, T2>` class given in some library somewhere, or write your own, then make a list of that.

Comment: @user3030010 As I understood it, the OP wants a list of exactly 2 elements: one Foo and one Bar. In other words, a tuple/pair.

Comment: @Klitos Kyriacou: Yes @user3030010: I did a bad example, instead of `Foo` and `Bar`, consider a `File` and a `FileReader` instance, which only makes sense in combination/as pair.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Groovy has the notion of [Tuples](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Tuple.html).

```
def tuple = new Tuple('one', 1)
def (String a, Integer b) = tuple
println a
println b
```

or alternatively

```
def doSomething(String s, Integer i) {
  println s
  println i
}
doSomething(tuple)
```

or alternatively

```
def doSomething(Tuple t) {
  println t[0]
  println t[1]
}
doSomething(tuple)
```

then you can do

```
def tuples = [ ] << tuple << tuple
tuples.each { doSomething(it) }
```

Comment: And if you want generics, there's `Tuple2`, ie:  `new Tuple2<Foo, Bar>(foo, bar)`

Comment: How is this list of objects.. looks like just tuple, since when tuple is a list of tuples?
Question clearly ask how to create a list that contains two object, each object in a list is two objects, not one object of two items.

Comment: @AistisTaraskevicius The first part of my answer talks about tuples as a way of storing the "object" data, as it has nice abstractions in Groovy as shown by my examples. The last part then shows how you can make a list of tuples (def tuples = [ ] << tuple << tuple) and iterate over them (tuples.each { doSomething(it) }).

Answer (score 2):

Consider Groovy's [Expando](http://mrhaki.blogspot.ca/2009/10/groovy-goodness-expando-as-dynamic-bean.html). For example:

```
class Foo {}
class Bar {}

def fooBar = new Expando()
fooBar."foo" = new Foo()
fooBar."bar" = new Bar()

def fooBars = []
fooBars << fooBar

fooBars.each { item  ->
    def foo = item."foo"
    def bar = item."bar"

    assert foo instanceof Foo
    assert bar instanceof Bar
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a list of lists? Each element of the list could be a two-element list containing a `Foo` and `Bar` instance in that order.

For added safety when constructing each two-element Foo/Bar list, write a helper method that's TypeChecked and returns an immutable list to prevent post-construction tampering.

```
@TypeChecked
def makeFooBar(Foo foo, Bar bar) { 
    [foo, bar].asImmutable() 
}

def fooBars = [] 

// some code to populate the list...
fooBars << makeFooBar(new Foo(), new Bar())

// iterate and do something with each foo/bar pair
fooBars.each { fooBar ->
  def (foo, bar) = fooBar

}
```

The one type unsafe area is the `fooBars` list, which can be populated with other object types. But if you want that degree of type safety, then maybe you should consider a different language altogether.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What do you mean with "consider a different language"? (I come from PHP world btw) :)

Comment: I just meant that if you want to use generics and have them mean something, you should consider Java instead of Groovy. Groovy, by default, doesn't strictly honor generic signatures; it will happily run the code `List<Integer> list = ['hi', 'there']`. But the best way to deal with this looseness, in my opinion, is to embrace Groovy's attitude and write your code as `def list = ['hi', 'there']`. Overall, though, if you come from a PHP perspective, I think Groovy will suit you well.

Answer (score 1):

Why did nobody suggest a map?

```
def x = [:]
x['foo'] = new Bar()
```

Seems a bit smarter than a list of tuples.